# SocketException Connection failed

Tags: c#, sockets

I use the sample code on `MSDN` but it cannot work.

Below is code:

```
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[2];
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.Connect(ipEndPoint);
```

Comment: What does the _ipAddr_ `IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[2];` show?

Comment: `ipHost.AddressList[2]` is `192.168.1.90`

Comment: Then there is not server active (like Paul Farry says), you know what you're connecting on port 11000?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to also have an Active TcpListener on your local machine (i'm guessing by using Dns.GetHostname()).

Instead of relying on DNS when trying to connect back to yourself, you can use `IPAddress.Loopback`

Answer (score 0):

The code that MSDN provided is for example. This means it may not work in all circumstances.

The problem you facing is, that there is no software listening on the port 11000. (for a client to connect on a port, there should be a server listening.) irl same like: *If you (client) phone your friend, but your friend(server) isn't home(listening) to pick up the homephone, there will be no conversation. ;-)*

Comment: OH, I know what you mean. Thank you very much.